# PHP causing a gap between header and banner

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a static home page that I'm trying to upload to wordpress. I've managed to get the site to look the way I want in html but whenever I try opening it in wordpress, it creates a huge gap. I have no idea where it's coming from. I googled this and kept hearing about BOM with UTF-8. I have brackets so i'm not sure if it saves with/without BOM.

here's what php makes it look like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuYf9.png)

here's what I want it to look like [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRZOb.png)

the site address is mustafasprojects.com

html code

```
<!-- Header -->
            <header id="header">
                <h1>Mustafa's Projects</h1>
                <nav>
                    <ul> 
                        <li><a href="#intro">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">Who I Am</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#portfolio">My Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </header>
```

css

```
#header {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 10000;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.95);
        height: 3em;
        line-height: 3em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0.15em 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
        animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 SlideInFromTop;
    }

        #header h1 {
            height: 3em;
            left: 1em;
            line-height: 3em;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: -.225em;
            font-size: 1.2em;
        }

        #header h1 a {
                color: #000
                font-size: 1.1em;
                border: 0;
} 

        #header nav {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0.5em;
            top: .525em;
            height: 1em;
            line-height: 1em;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

            #header nav ul {
                margin: 0;
            }

                #header nav ul li {
                    display: inline-block;
                    margin-left: 0.5em;
                    font-size: 0.95em;

                }

                        #header nav > ul > li a {
                        display: inline-block;
                        height: 1.7em;
                        line-height: 1.7em;
                        padding: 0 .3em;
                        border-radius: 6px;
                    }

                    #header nav > ul > li a:not(.button) {
                        color: #000;
                        display: inline-block;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        border: 0;
                    }

                        #header nav > ul > li a:not(.button).icon:before {
                            color: #999;
                            margin-right: 0.5em;
                        }

                        #header nav > ul > li a:hover:not(.active) {
                            background-color: #266dd3;
                        }
                #header nav > ul > li:first-child {
                        margin-left: 0;
                    }
            #header nav > ul > li.active a:not(.button) {
                        background-color: rgba(153, 153, 153, 0.25);
                    }
                    #header nav > ul > li .button {
                        margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
                        position: relative;
                    }
    .header.onload-header-fade-down {
            transform: 0.75s ease-in-out;
        transition: opacity .75s ease-in-out, transform .75s ease-in-out;
}
    body {
        padding-top: 3em;
    }
```

with php

>

```
    <div id="page-wrapper">

    <!-- Header -->
        <header id="header">
            <h1>Mustafa's Projects</h1>
            <nav>
                <?php html5blank_nav(); ?>
            </nav>
        </header>
```

I opened it up in inspector and it seems my main class extends to the top of "Home" and my header extends to the proper length. so is it just a question of checking padding in "main"?

Comment: where is the PHP  ?????

Comment: It's probably not PHP, but the wordpress theme has styles applied to those elements that are not present when you just render the html and styles you have written. You have to take the theme's styles into account, and override where needed. You could use the dom inspector/dev tools to see what is being applied to your elements.

Comment: added the php to the post

Comment: I'm looking at the site and I'm not seeing the issue (the image is missing and there are broken img references, but otherwise looks ok)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main `<div>` wrapper seems to be causing the gap:

```
#page-wrapper {
    padding-top: 3em;
}
```